# App Store Software Update download speed is super slow

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

My connection right now is 200 Mbit/s download and upload for any kind of internet usage except downloads over the app store.

I want to download a software update and I'm getting maybe 1 Mbit/s.

I tried these "fixes" I found in the internet:

- I turned Certificate Revocation List (CRL) in the Keychain Access preferences off.
- I changed my DNS to 8.8.8.8.

It doesn't help. The downloads stay super slow. What can I do?

Comment: Clearly the problem is not on your site.

Comment: Maybe Apple's content delivery network was just being slow that day.